# Customize back button in IOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

How can I make a customize back button without Text in iOS using barmetrics?

I wanna make something like http://a397.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/081/Purple/v4/e6/be/2d/e6be2d9e-dc95-7e44-b1ed-9386fa9f4d02/mzl.zwjkpepo.320x480-75.jpg

Comment: This is an oft asked question! Check out: http://www.verious.com/component/custom-back-button/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300503/make-a-custom-back-button-for-uinavigationcontroller

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]
            setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"]
            forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

You can place that in your app delegate and it will set the background image to all back buttons in the app (for that control state and bar metrics, of course).

**Edit:**
If you want to something different then use this code:

```
- (void)setBackButton
{
    UIButton *backButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton] autorelease];
}

- (void)backButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? 
I tried this. The image is coming but its taking the full size of back button rather than the image size. "Back" is also getting displayed :(

Comment: You can use second approach, for this you can find so many solution on google.

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998438/custom-back-button-image-on-the-navigation-bar-doesnt-work-iphone-sdk

Comment: This workaround is not 100% good as it removes the swipe transition for the UINavigationController

Answer (score 0):

How about Something like this?

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(YourFrame)];

[backButton setTitle:@"<" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(callSelectorMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton] autorelease];

[backButton release],backButton=nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution:**

```
 UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(popBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Thanks to [Best Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1091348/best-coder)